# How to delete usages when you delete certain file

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have run into a problem, where I wanted to delete a .css usage

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

after I clicked on that file in assets/css, the window popped up that I have 146 usages of that file (that's correct, it is on purpose).

[image]

When I go to `View Usages`
I see following:

[image]

But when I click on `Do Refactor`, nothing happens and the usage is still there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47436 to be notified on updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have run to conclusion, I felt the need to post it here for future searches:

The thing is, Webstorm is **not** that smart to run recursively through the whole code and find usages and thereafter delete them. If you delete a file and you are using it somewhere else, you just need to search it and delete it.